# How is broadcasting applying in this example of numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I am learning numpy and am a bit confused about broadcasting, here is  my set up. I have two matrices

```
>>> y=np.array([1,2,3])
>>> v = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> r=np.reshape(v, (3, 1))
```

So r is (3*1) matrix while y is a rank 1 matrix with shape being(3,).

If I do y.dot(r), I get 14, assuming that numpy applies broadcasting on y, making it (1*3) and then it does the dot product with r(3*1) so resulting matrix will be 1*1.

However when I do r.dot(y), it throws an error. Why doesn't it do the same thing here? It should make y(1*3) and r being(3*1), it should give a  3*3 matrix. What is wrong with this reasoning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The normal broadcasting does not apply in `np.dot`.  It's docs say:

> For N dimensions it is a sum product over the last axis of `a` and
>   the second-to-last of `b`::

`y` is `(3,)`; `r` is `(3,1)`.

In `y*r`, broadcasting applies, `y` is reshaped to `(1,3)`, and the result is `(3,3)`.

In `np.dot(y,r)`, the last axis of `y` is `3`, 2nd last of `r` is also `3`, multiply and sum, the shape is `(1,)`.  Note that if `y` starts as `(1,3)`, the result is 2d:

```
In [445]: np.dot(y.reshape(1,3),r).shape
Out[445]: (1, 1)
```

In `np.dot(r,y)`, last axis of `r` is `1`, 2nd to last (only) of `y` is `3` - hence the mismatch.

Expanding `y` does produce the `(3,3)`:

```
In [449]: np.dot(r,y.reshape(1,3))
Out[449]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

Answer (score 2):

It's just like matrix multiplication on paper where the two inner dimensions need to agree.  So if you want a 3x3 not only does r need to be of shape (3,1) but y needs to be of shape (1,3) not (3,)

Like so:

```
In [60]: r.dot(y.reshape(1,-1))
Out[60]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

I feel like numpy should infer this, but I guess "explicit is better than implicit"